# How to add a bean in SpringBootTest

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing

The question seems extremely simple, but strangely enough I didn't find a solution.

My question is about adding/declaring a bean in a `SpringBootTest`, not overriding one, nor mocking one using mockito.

Here is what I got when trying the simplest implementation of my real need (but it doesn't work):

Some service, bean, and config:

```
@Value // lombok
public class MyService {
    private String name;
}
```

---

```
@Value // lombok
public class MyClass {
    private MyService monitoring;
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class SomeSpringConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyClass makeMyClass(MyService monitoring){
        return new MyClass(monitoring);
    }
}
```

---

The test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SomeSpringConfig.class })
public class SomeSpringConfigTest {

    private String testValue = "testServiceName";

    // this bean is not used
    @Bean
    public MyService monitoringService(){ return new MyService(testValue); }

    // thus this bean cannot be constructed using SomeSpringConfig 
    @Autowired
    public MyClass myClass;

    @Test
    public void theTest(){
        assert(myClass.getMonitoring().getName() == testValue);
    }
}
```

Now, if I replace the `@Bean public MyService monitoring(){ ... }` by `@MockBean public MyService monitoring;`, it works. I find it strange that I can easily mock a bean, but not simply provide it.

=> So how should I add a bean of my own for one test?

Edit:

- I think [ThreeDots's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773519/1206998) (create a config test class) is the general recommendation.
- However, [Danylo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57773314/1206998) (use @ContextConfiguration) fit better to what I asked, i.e. add @Bean directly in the test class.

Comment: Your test class isn't a configuration class so placing `@Bean` methods in there won't do a thing.

Comment: I tried to add `@Configuration` before the test class, but It doesn't work...

Comment: just create new configuration class (not in src, but in test folder) similar to `SomeSpringConfig` where you define your bean and then include it in `@SpringBootTest(classes = { SomeSpringConfig.class, AnotherConfig.class })`.

Comment: Well it works, indeed (you can make an answer). But it seems quite too much to make a new config class especially when it is so simple to add a mocked bean. I am wrong?

Comment: `@MockBean` is especiall for that, why would you want/need an `@Configuration` class for that?

Comment: No I want to add a real bean, not a mocked one. But I find it strange that it is easier to add a mocked bean than a real one. Spring being very mature, I would expect that either there is a good and simple way to add a real bean, or otherwise that there is a good reason not to do so which explains why it is not as easy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring Test needs to know what configuration you are using (and hence where to scan for beans that it loads). To achieve what you want you have more options, the most basic ones are these two:

1. Create configuration class outside the test class that includes your bean

   ```
   @Configuration
   public class TestConfig {

       @Bean
       public MyService monitoringService() {
           return new MyService();
       }
   }
   ```

and then add it to to test as configuration class `@SpringBootTest(classes = { SomeSpringConfig.class, TestConfig.class })`

or

2. If you only need to use this configuration in this particular test, you can define it in static inner class

   ```
   public class SomeSpringConfigTest {

       @Configuration
       static class ContextConfiguration {

           @Bean
           public MyService monitoringService() {
               return new MyService();
           }
       }
   }
   ```

this will be automatically recognized and loaded by spring boot test

Comment: For some reason, static inner class was not recognized in a very similar case.

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the config as

```
@ContextHierarchy({
    @ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeSpringConfig.class)
})
```

Comment: it works with your code but using the test class (SomeSpringConfigTest). But it can be simplifyied to simply `@ContextConfiguration(classes = SomeSpringConfigTest.class)` before the class definition. I. no @ContextHierarchy.

Comment: Maybe you should add a little explanation of what are doing those decorations, thus how it provides what I ask?

Answer (score 3):

What i am using in this cases is `@Import`:

```
@DataJpaTest(showSql = false)
//tests against the real data source defined in properties
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@Import(value = {PersistenceConfig.class, CustomDateTimeProvider.class})
class MessageRepositoryTest extends PostgresBaseTest {
....
```

Here i am using a pre configured "test slice".
In this case a need to add my JpaAuditingConfig.

But why not just adding the other beans as you did with your `SomeSpringConfig.class` ?:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = { SomeSpringConfig.class, OtherBean.class })
public class SomeSpringConfigTest {
...
```

Everything listed in test will be injectable directly, all not declared must be added as mocks.